# mPDF issue with SLIM 3

Tags: mpdf, slim-3

iam building a application in SLIM 3 where i need to generate a PDF Certificate.
so i have added mPDF library extension in my SLIM application.
and i tried to generate a test pdf with:

```
use Mpdf\Mpdf;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
/**
 * Class GenerateCertificate
 * @package saikatbepari\pdf
 */
 class GeneratePDF
 {

   public function generateCertificate(Request $request, Response $response)
  {
    $response = $response->withHeader( 'Content-type', 'application/pdf' );
    $mpdf = new Mpdf(['tempDir' => '../tmp']);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
    $mpdf->Output();
  }


}
```

and the output which i got is :

[image]

can anyone please help me out, what is the issue and how to fix it.
any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Here's my simple solution

```
$app->get('/testing_mpdf/', 'testingMpdf');
function testingMpdf($request, $returned, $args) {
  $mpdf     = new Mpdf();
  $mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
  $mpdf->Output();
  return $returned->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Slim framework probably resets content-type. Try returning a string from mPDF and setting it as a body to your PSR7 response:

```
// ...
$body = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');
$stream = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for($body);
$response = $response->withBody($stream);

return $response;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Follow this ocde

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => **DIR** . '/tmp']);
    $url="http://localhost/ephotobook/homelink/login/75100/Screen%20Shot%202019-03-02%20at%2012.32.14%20PM.png";
    $h="30%";
    $w="40%";
        $db = new DbOperation();
        $res=$db->showimagesbyid(75100);
        $b=$res['data'];
        $tr="";
        foreach ($b as $r) {
            $url1="http://localhost/ephotobook/homelink/login/75100/".rawurlencode($r['Filename']); 
            $tr.="";
        }
    $html ="
        
        
            
            This Is Image Sorting

```
    <div>
        <div>
            .$tr.    
    </div> 
    </body>
    </html>";

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //$mpdf->WriteHTML(wireRenderFile('../invoice.php'));
    $mpdf->Output('../pdf/invoice5.pdf', 'F');
```